# VS2008 javascript debugger IE8 "there is no source code available for the current location"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have almost the same problem  as this unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625903/visual-studio-2010-script-debugger-doesnt-work-for-me). The only difference is I'm using VS2008, but I'm in an MVC project calling this javascript function:

```
function CompanyChange(compCtrl) {
alert(compCtrl.value);
debugger;
var test;
for (var i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
    test = document.all[i];

}
}
```

I hit the alert, then I get the message "there is no source code available for the current location." At which point the page becomes unresponsive and I have to manually stop the debugger just to shut it down.

I've logged into another machine and ran this exact code and it works fine, I hit the debugger and can step through. I've checked to make sure all settings in VS>Tools>Options>Debugging are identical as well as IE>Options>Advanced and they are. Both machines are Windows 7 Enterprise edition 32-bit, VS2008, IE8.

I've also tried attaching a process manually in VS, and using the 'Developer Tools' in IE which didn't work (said there already was a process attached).

I was hoping someone may have had this problem and found a work-around because I've already done a lot of searching and tried all the options I've read. Anyone else run into this?

Thank you,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently answered the original question, so thought I'd post my answer here too:

The debugger cannot debug both Silverlight code and Script code at the same time, if the Silverlight debugger is selected JavaScript debugging is switched off.

To resolve this go to the Project's Properties and select "Start Options". Next check that the Silverlight checkbox is NOT ticked if you want to be able to debug JavaScript. (It is unfortunate that the UI here is not clear about this side effect.)

Comment: He said MVC, not silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same "Source code not available" msg for ie8. Actually I was having 2 different methods with same names having different parameters in 2 different pages and one of the method which I was invoking was not getting called due to the overloaded method which Ie8 doesn't detect. So I just renamed the function and it resolved the issue