# Visual studio 2010 does not break at the break point in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Visual studio 2010 does not break at the break point in javascript,
I use InternetExplorer in debug mode, aspx page.
I run the application with F5.
I set the break point in the javascript code but the visual studio does not break at the break point.
Anyone meet this problem?

Thanks everyone....

Comment: Surely a great deal more detail is required for anyone to meaningfully answer this question?

Comment: How are you launching your debugger (F5, Attach to Process)?

Comment: Are breakpoints in server-side code being hit? And are you using IIS or Cassini?

Comment: I want that the code will break on the server side but this is not break, i am use IIS, thanks...

Comment: Try adding `debugger;` line in your code - any luck?

Comment: *"I want that the code will break on the server side but this is not break"* You're running JavaScript code server-side? Are you *sure*? Don't get me wrong, it's possible, JavaScript isn't just a client-side language and I use it on the server all the time. (Though if you're in a VS.Net 2010 project, you'd probably be running JScript.Net server-side rather than actual JavaScript.) But *most people* only use JavaScript on the client (browser);  I suspect you're getting confused about what's running where...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have Silverlight debugging disabled for that project, as per Mister Cook's answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769167/110549

That was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a previous cached version of your javascript code. In your browser window (ex. internet explorer), you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and it should refresh any cached js or css files that the browser may be holding. I've made it a habit to refresh with every debugging session.

If you don't like doing this every time, you can always use a tool such as [CSS Refresh](http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl), which pretty much does it for you and then some.