# Unable to debug javascript in VS2010 with SP1

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am using Asp.Net MVC project and using jQuery to code JavaScript. Problem is I am not able to debug JavaScript. I searched for this issue and found a few threads. Basically this one:

[Visual Studio 2010 script debugger doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625903/visual-studio-2010-script-debugger-doesnt-work-for-me)

And

[The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document in a Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301216/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-do)

None of these are currently working for me. I tried to launch my application in Chrome and IE9 but my breakpoint just doesn't get hit.

Can you tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried FireFox/Firebug?

Comment: No. Actually I am first trying in VS itself. I found that if I write debugger; in some function the debugging works nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use IE9 with the F12 developer tools, FF5/FireBug and Chrome. They all have good javaScript debuggers. It's a good idea to use all of them.